# Polymer 1.0: Clickable item in dom-repeat to e.g. iron-page which contains further info (contact list)

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm setting up a contact list in Polymer 1.0. When the user clicks on a name, there should be a (animated) page opened for further details. All of these data elements are pulled from an external .json file.

Two questions for this approach..:

1) where to begin? How do I wrap, for example, an iron-page or neon-animated-page around my current setup (which is searchable, which is also the -temporary- reason it's a dom-repeat instead of an iron-list):

```
<template id="resultlist" is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}" filter="contactFilter">
  <paper-item>
    <paper-item-body two-line>
      <div>{{item.name}}</div>
      <div secondary>{{item.number}}</div>
    </paper-item-body>
  </paper-item>
</template>
```

2) For quick try-out with binding options I've created an paper-dialog (instead of an page behaviour) which displays further data for the chosen person... On top of that paper-dialog should the chosen name being displayed. But I only get the first name of the array in my .json file. How can I setup the code to display the `{{item.name}}` of the chosen item?

Ps. I'm aware of the contacts-app from Rob Dodson (https://github.com/robdodson/contacts-app), but I can't figure out how it should be done in Polymer 1.0.

---

Update 27.10.2015

After [Hugo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256314/polymer-1-0-clickable-item-in-dom-repeat-to-e-g-iron-page-which-contains-furth/33262311?noredirect=1#comment54385213_33262311) answer I'm not able to get the solution to work in an dom-module structure.

Sorry for misunderstanding, but I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

Having to following:

**phonebook.html**, which acts like an index

```
...

<body unresolved>

<template is="dom-bind" id="application">
  <neon-animated-pages selected="[[selected]]" entry-animation="fade-in-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
    <contact-list></contact-list>
    <contact-details></contact-details>
  </neon-animated-pages>
</template>

<script>

  var application = document.querySelector('#application');
    application.selected = 0;

  document.addEventListener('show-details', function() {
    application.selected = 1;
  });

  document.addEventListener('show-list', function() {
    application.selected = 0;
  });

</script>

</body>
```

DOM-module **contact-list.html**, the list it self.

```
<dom-module id="contact-list">

  <template>

    <style include="phonebook-styles"></style>

    <iron-ajax url="../data/data.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax>

    <div class="container">

      <h3>Contactlist:</h3>

        <div class="template-container">          

        <template is="dom-repeat" id="templateUsers" items="{{data}}">
          <paper-item on-tap="showDetails">
            <paper-item-body two-line>
              <div>{{item.name}}</div>
              <div secondary>{{item.phonenumber}}</div>
            </paper-item-body>
            <div class="item-details-link">
              <iron-icon icon="account-circle"></iron-icon>
            </div>
          </paper-item>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>

<script>

Polymer({

  is: 'contact-list',

  properties: {
    selectedContact:{
        type:Object,
        value:function(){
          return null;
        }
      }
  },

  showDetails: function(ev) {        
    var data = this.$.templateUsers.itemForElement(ev.target);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(data)) // works with data chosen data selection...
    this.selectedContact = data;
    this.fire('show-details', this.selectedContact);
  }

  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

DOM-module **contact-details.html**, the details-list.

```
<dom-module id="contact-details">

  <template>
      <!-- Do I need to declare the .json in my details module? -->
      <iron-ajax url="../data/data.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}" auto></iron-ajax> 

      <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back" on-tap="showList"></paper-icon-button>

      <h3>Contact details</h3>

      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
        <div>{{selectedContact.name}}</div>
      </template>

    </template>

  <script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'contact-details',

    showList: function() {
      this.fire('show-list');
    }

   });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Everything, like the transitions, work. The chosen contact is also displayed in an alertbox (commented out in `contact-list.html`), but isn't forwarded to the `contact-details.html` page.

Comment: The demo page for neon-animations might help you to get started https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages. The element source contains the source for the demo page too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple steps to implement the solution:

- Setup the neon animated pages ( one page would be the contact list, the other page would be the details )
- Display the list of contacts  ( you already have this one )
- Add a "selectedContact" property to your element
- Add a tap/click handler to the list items element and inside the handler set the selectedContact. You need to get the contact item from the DOM element clicked. ( Check an example here : http://jsbin.com/lofarabare/6/edit )
- You can bind the contact details page elements to the selectedContact properties, e.g {{selectedContact.name}}
- Inside the handler also Change the neon animated pages selected property to have it display the animation to the other page.
  -- Extra feedback

I checked the way you handle events, feedback below:

- Give the elements some id so you can add the event listener directly to them (e.g application.$.myContactList.addEventListener('show-detail',function(ev){...})
- The way you fire the event from the contact-list is correct, however you are not reading the event data inside the event listener for the 'show-detail' event. The event listener receives the event as argument "ev". You can get the event data using ev.detail
- With the event data (the selected contact) you can update your contact details component. Give it some id like 'details' and just update the 'selectedContact' property. **You need to declare the selectedContact in the details component, right now you don't have it there **

Comment: Hi, thanks for your helpful comment. Digging further into the neon-animated-pages I've recreated the app structure so it works with my dom-repeat setup as shown above. (With help of a template from Dodson's Polycasts - https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/tree/master/ep25-neon-animated-pages/basic-animation).

Point 1 to 4 are clear. Point 4 works with the alertbox shown in your jsbin, but is fired - like in the jsbin - from the contactlist itself, probably because it's declared in the contactlist offcourse. At this point i'm lost. Is it possible to clearify the handlings a bit more?

Comment: The alert is there just to show how you can get the bound item. Instead of the alert you can just change the selected page.

Comment: You can check the updated JSBin including the neon animation pages here http://jsbin.com/wupefomuwe/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for your working example! Almost there... Although my dom-module for the contactslist is a seperate template file. The code `this.$.pages.selected=1;` throws a console error where 'selected' is not defined. 'selected' works from the index file (like [this](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/blob/master/ep25-neon-animated-pages/basic-animation/index.html) example, where my structure is based on. How do I `this.$.pages.selected=1;` - which is placed into my separate dom-module for the contactslist -  to be working..?

Comment: You could fire and event inside the contactlist element : this.fire('contactSelected', eventDataHere) , and subscribe to the event in some place you have access to the neon animated pages so you could set its selected property.

Comment: Edited the opening post with my current dom-module setup. Could you review it and point me where I'm wrong?

Comment: I added some feedback based on your updates. You are firing the event with the correct parameter, but in the listener you need to do something with the data, in your case, assign it to some property of the 'details' component ( The property could have the same name 'selectedContact', but it's not the same of the list component)

Comment: Thanks again. I really want to vote your answer to be the perfect one, but i'm a bit annoyed of my bad knowledge of Polymer. Created [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dvtigzoJuOkVRUenwkHS?p=preview) with the code I just have.., could you please take a look at it and help me out? I'm sure it must be simple, but i'm lost at this point somewhere.

Comment: I checked the Plnkr and did the changes I described above. In contact-details you were using iron ajax again but that's not necessary since you already have the contact details. http://plnkr.co/edit/SF9Pun48f7cDXll2VzsT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Originally i'd embed the `{{selectedContact.name}}` in a dom-repeat, but it shouldn't. Thanks again for your help :-).

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Good luck